# Get unicode characters as string when reading response body (Golang)

Tags: go, web-scraping, html-parsing

I'm scraping a website that was written in Polish, meaning it contains characters such as ź and ę.

When I attempt to parse the html, either using the html package or even by splitting the string of the response body, I get output like this:

```
���~♦�♀�����r�▬֭��↔��q���y���<p��19��lFۯ☻→Z�7��
```

Im currently using

```
bodyBytes, err := ioutil.Readall(resp.body)
if err != nil {
  //handle
} 
bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
```

In order to get the string

How can I get the text in readable format?

Comment: Inspect the content-type header of the response. Use the [appropriate encoding package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding#section-directories) to convert to UTF-8 (most likely [charmap](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7/encoding/charmap)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

Since the content encoding of the response was gzip, the code below worked for getting the response as a printable string

```
gReader, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
gBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gReader)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
gReader.Close()
bodyStr := string(gBytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

on wich website are you working ?
I'm getting correct characters when I'm testing on wikipedia page

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_alphabet")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    b, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    bodyStr := string(b)
    fmt.Println(bodyStr)
}
```

```
<td>Ą</td>
<td>Ć</td>
<td>Ę</td>
```

Comment: [dhl proof of delivery](https://webpod.dhl.com/webPOD/DHLePODRequest) page, it might be that my http client decodes gzip differently, but I've checked previous requests. They all have the same content type and content-encoding headers, so I'm not sure what the difference could be on this request

Comment: I believe it may be because the request protocol was HTTP/1.1, instead of HTTP/2.0

Comment: is it possible for you to get the curl of the request you are doing ? for exemple on wikipedia i can see more informations here https://ibb.co/Tw60Wtd, if you could copy paste we might be able to reproduce/locate the error